# java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format for milliseconds

Tags: java, date, logging, java.util.logging

I am using JUL for logging, I have a properties file. I want to log datetime in milliseconds in my log file.

This is my property:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tl:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$Tp %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%n
```

Above logs something like this:

```
Dec 05, 2016 5:08:06 PM ...
```

How can I also show millisecond?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html shows all possible formatting options, which are used also by the `SimpleFormatter`.

So in your case it is `%1$tL` for the milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Use `%1$tL`:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tl:%1$tM:%1$tS.%1$tL %1$Tp %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%n
                                                                                ^^^
```

I based this answer off [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186682/how-to-configure-glassfish-logging-to-show-milliseconds-in-timestamps).