# How to add milliscond field in jetty request log?

Tags: java, http, logging, request, jetty

The default timestamp in jetty's request log is supporting second level only. 
How to record the arrival time of a request on the millisecond level?

Comment: The built-in Jetty request logging follows NCSA formatting / syntax.  Millisecond is not part of that.  You would be better off using `logback-access`, and paying attention to the nuances about what that timestamp actually means (hint: its not request arrival)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks, it is really helpful!http://logback.qos.ch/access.html

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Jetty Administration Guide - Chapter 11. Jetty Logging](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-logging.html) it can use various logging libraries.  You'll have to include details on the Jetty configuration.

If it is setup using `java.util.logging` then you can set the pattern by following: [How to configure GlassFish logging to show milliseconds in timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186682/how-to-configure-glassfish-logging-to-show-milliseconds-in-timestamps).